# finding reoccuring string in I/O stream -C?

Tags: c, realloc, fseek, ftell

I'm quite new to C. I'm trying to write a code that finds a string in a I/O stream, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I know the error is probably in the large while loop (in the code below). 
I want the function to return the location in bytes from the beginning of the stream and -1 if it fails for some reason. It just keeps returning -1 for any file I try it on.

```
long find_string(const char *str, const char *filename, long offset)
{
FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
if (!f){
    return -1;
}

int s=0,c;

c = fgetc(f);
if(c == EOF){
    return -1;
}

char *check = malloc(sizeof(char));

fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END); // Sees and stores how long the file is
long sz = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);

if(fseek(f, offset,SEEK_SET) != 0){ // finds the position of offset
    return -1;
}


while(fgetc(f) != EOF){
    c = fgetc(f);
    if(c == str[0] && ftell(f) < sz){
        check[0] = c;
        offset = ftell(f);
        }

        s++;
        for (unsigned int r=1; r < (strlen(str));r++){
            c = fgetc(f);
            if(c == str[s]){
                    check = realloc(check, sizeof(char)*s);
                    check[s] = c;
                    s++;
            }                   
        }

    if(strcmp(check, str)==0){
        free(check);
        fclose(f);
        break;

    }
    else{
        check = realloc(check, sizeof(char));
        offset = -1;
    }
}
return offset;}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Ouch.  I don't know what your specific problem is but you have made this 3 times harder than it has to be.  Consider rethinking the whole thing.

Comment: In order to teach you how to fish, rather than returning -1 for all errors, you could return different values.  That at least will tell you what section of the function is failing (and would also help us)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: searching for a string in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188914/c-searching-for-a-string-in-a-file)

Comment: "what I'm doing wrong" — basically just about everything.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier if you simply memory-mapped the entire file and ran a standard string searching algorithm on it.

For memory mapping, see: [Linux - Memory Mapped File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269176/linux-memory-mapped-file)

For string searching code, see: [strstr() for a string that is NOT null-terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584644/strstr-for-a-string-that-is-not-null-terminated)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the lines with comment updated

```
long find_string(const char *str, const char *filename, long offset)
{
FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
if (!f){
    return -1;
}

int s=0,c;

c = fgetc(f);
if(c == EOF){
    return -1;
}

char *check = malloc(sizeof(char));

fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END); // Sees and stores how long the file is
long sz = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);

if(fseek(f, offset,SEEK_SET) != 0){ // finds the position of offset
    return -1;
}

    c = fgetc(f); // Updated
while(c != EOF){ // Updated
    if(c == str[0] && ftell(f) < sz){
        check[0] = c;
        offset = ftell(f);
        }

        s++;
        for (unsigned int r=1; r < (strlen(str));r++){
            c = fgetc(f);
            if(c == str[s]){
                    check = realloc(check, sizeof(char)*s);
                    check[s] = c;
                    s++;
            }                   
        }

    if(strcmp(check, str)==0){
        free(check);
        fclose(f);
        break;

    }
    else{
        check = realloc(check, sizeof(char));
        offset = -1;
    }
    c = fgetc(f); //Updated
}
return offset;}
```

since you are using fgetc at the condition and start of the look, you actually comparing the second char of file with first char of str. update and check.